# What is the usage of comma in augmented list assignment?

Tags: python, syntax

I saw a Python syntax like this:

```
l = []
l += 8,
```

The result of `l` is `[8]`, apparently the comma after `8` changes the integer iterable so that it could add with a list.

Without the comma:

```
l = []
l += 8
```

It will have an error of `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I searched online but didn't find any helpful explanation of this kind of syntax. Is there any document I could refer to the comma in Python or any other usages of comma?

Answer (score 2):

This is old but I was trying to understand the same syntax recently, and here is what I found:

```
l=[]
l+=8,
```

This code has 2 parts -

1. A single value followed by a comma creates a tuple(an iterable) with the single value, so,

   ```
   l+=8,    ## implies l+=(8,)
   ```
2. The augmented assignment operator `+=` calls the in-place method `__iadd__` 
   and is implemented as `sq_inplace_concat` for the list `l`, explaining the concatenation of list and tuple. Quoted from [PEP 203: Augmented Assignments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/#id3):

   > Some special casing exists to account for the case of + and *, which have a special meaning for sequences: for +, sequence concatenation, no coercion what so ever is done if a C type defines sq_concat or sq_inplace_concat.

   Essentially, the operator behaves as an `extend()` function for the list and modifies the list in-place by extending it with the following iterable(tuple in this case).

   ```
   l=[]     
   l+=8,    ## eventually implies l.extend((8,))
   print(l) ## [8]
   ```

The fact that list.extend() function accepts only iterables explains the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.